# Issue with elastic mapping both dynamic and static

Tags: elasticsearch, search, mapping

I have this issue with elastic. I want to have both dynamic and static mapping on parts of the index.

I have made the following mapping:

```
{"settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "date_detection": false,
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
          "time": {
            "properties": {
              "insert": {
                "type": "date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "traits": {
        "properties": {
          "private": {
            "dynamic": true
          },
          "public": {
            "dynamic": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I I get the following error:

**Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No type specified for field [private]**

What am I missing. I want the part of **traits.private** of the index to be dynamic so the user can add any data.

Is it event possible with elastic or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but the error message you get is because you haven't defined the `object` type for `private` and `public`. If you do, the index can be created successfully:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "date_detection": false,
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
          "time": {
            "properties": {
              "insert": {
                "type": "date"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "traits": {
        "properties": {
          "private": {
            "type": "object",       <--- add this
            "dynamic": true
          },
          "public": {
            "type": "object",       <--- add this
            "dynamic": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. Now I know what I was missing. :)